# Powershell test if folder empty

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, how do I test if a directory is empty?

Comment: Whoever downvoted didn't comment on why. Upvoting.

Comment: @SpellingD: I wish it was like that all the time. :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this...

```
$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\temp | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count #Returns the count of all of the objects in the directory
```

If `$directoryInfo.count -eq 0`, then your directory is empty.

Comment: `gci` won't display hidden files by default, so you'll need the `-force` parameter to ensure the directory is truly empty.

Comment: Do we have to find each file? This can be time consuming.

Comment: @SpellingD that will fail because a folder is really empty, but  using `-force` will turn up the `desktop.ini` hidden system file

Comment: "directoryInfo.count" does NOT return the count of all files in the directory, but rather it returns the count of all files AND sub-directories inside. so if you have 0 files but 1 sub-folder it returns 1.

Comment: @Benjamin edited for clarity.  If you do want to only check if there are no _files_ in a directory, add the `-file` parameter to Get-ChildItem, e.g. `$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -file | Measure-Object`

Answer (score 93):

If you are not interested in hidden or system files you can also use Test-Path

To see if it exists a file in directory `.\temp` you can use :

```
Test-Path -Path .\temp\*
```

or shortly :

```
Test-Path .\temp\*
```

Comment: +1 for such a neat way of checking. This should be accepted answer. BTW, you can even do `Test-Path .\temp\*` (without `-Path`).

Comment: Does anyone know if this still recurses through the entire glob? Or does it stop once it encounters *anything*?

Comment: Not sure to understand your question because if a directory exists inside temp, temp is no longer considered as empty.

Comment: @kenny It shouldn't recurse. It only needs to check in the single directory. At *most*, it should list the entire contents of that.

Comment: you can also negate with:  if (-Not (Test-Path .\temp\*) { }

Comment: This will return false if it is empty, but it will also return false if the dir is non-existant.

Answer (score 27):

To prevent enumerating  each file under c:\Temp (which can be time consuming), we can do somethings like this:

```
if((Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ -force | Select-Object -First 1 | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
{
   # folder is empty
}
```

Comment: This is by far the fastest solution as it doesn't enumerate through all files and just stops at the first one found. For checking if file(s) are present in a folder use `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'S:\Test\' -File -Force | Select-Object -First 1 | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0` instead of `Test-Path 'S:\Test\*' -PathType Leaf`.

Comment: Measure-Object isn't really adding anything here unless you're on PowerShell v1.

Comment: 2021 and this is still the fastest solution, by a long way.

Answer (score 6):

```
filter Test-DirectoryEmpty {
    [bool](Get-ChildItem $_\* -Force)
}
```

Comment: Why the !! ? Thank you for explain !

Comment: It's for converting the result to a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

One line:

```
if( (Get-ChildItem C:\temp | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
{
    #Folder Empty
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a waste to get all files and directories and count them only to determine if directory is empty. Much better to use .NET `EnumerateFileSystemInfos`

```
$directory = Get-Item -Path "c:\temp"
if (!($directory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos() | select -First 1))
{
    "empty"
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer because it does account for hidden (and possibly system) files.

Answer (score 3):

Simple approach

```
if (-Not (Test-Path .\temp*))
{
  # do your stuff here
}
```

you can remove `-Not` if you want to enter the 'if' when files are present.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `.GetFileSystemInfos().Count` to check the count of directories. [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos?view=netcore-3.1)

```
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path .\Documents\Test
$docs.GetFileSystemInfos().Count
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#Define Folder Path to assess and delete
$Folder = "C:\Temp\Stuff"

#Delete All Empty Subfolders in a Parent Folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

#Delete Parent Folder if empty
If((Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -force | Select-Object -First 1 | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {Remove-Item -Path $CATSFolder -Force -Recurse}
```

Comment: You can get serious problems here, if you use `-Path $_.FullName` in Get-ChildItem. Pleaase use [-LiteralPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721892/is-get-childitem-recurse-broken-when-there-are-square-brackets-in-the-input-pat/55367757#55367757) !!!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to JPBlanc, if directory path is $DirPath, this code also works for paths including square bracket characters.

```
    # Make square bracket non-wild card char with back ticks
    $DirPathDirty = $DirPath.Replace('[', '`[')
    $DirPathDirty = $DirPathDirty.Replace(']', '`]')

    if (Test-Path -Path "$DirPathDirty\*") {
            # Code for directory not empty
    }
    else {
            # Code for empty directory
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#################################################
# Script to verify if any files exist in the Monitor Folder
# Author Vikas Sukhija 
# Co-Authored Greg Rojas
# Date 6/23/16
#################################################


################Define Variables############ 
$email1 = "yourdistrolist@conoso.com" 
$fromadd = "yourMonitoringEmail@conoso.com" 
$smtpserver ="mailrelay.conoso.com" 

$date1 = get-date -Hour 1 -Minute 1 -Second 1
$date2 = get-date -Hour 2 -Minute 2 -Second 2 

###############that needs folder monitoring############################ 


$directory = "C:\Monitor Folder"

$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $directory | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count


if($directoryInfo.Count -gt '0') 
{ 

#SMTP Relay address 
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 

#Mail sender 
$msg.From = $fromadd 
#mail recipient 
$msg.To.Add($email1) 
$msg.Subject = "WARNING : There are " + $directoryInfo.count + " file(s) on " + $env:computername +  " in " + " $directory 
$msg.Body = "On " + $env:computername + " files have been discovered in the " + $directory + " folder."
$smtp.Send($msg) 

} 

Else
      { 
    Write-host "No files here" -foregroundcolor Green 
      }
```

Comment: While I certainly want to encourage you to post on StackOverflow, G, there are several "best practices" that you are ignoring, intentionally or otherwise. (a) Generally, you should not just post code without explanation. (b) You should not re-post the same answer given by someone else (yours has been given at least twice if you scroll through the answers here). (c) You should not include a whole bunch of unrelated code--90% of your code is irrelevant to the question asked. I'm not going to downvote, but just wanted you to be prepared in case you see some downvotes come along.

Answer (score 1):

Example of removing empty folder:

```
IF ((Get-ChildItem "$env:SystemDrive\test" | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
    remove-Item "$env:SystemDrive\test" -force
}
```

Comment: Please write your answer in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676).

Answer (score 1):

```
    $contents = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\New folder"
    if($contents.length -eq "") #If the folder is empty, Get-ChileItem returns empty string
    {
        Remove-Item "C:\New folder"
        echo "Empty folder. Deleted folder"
    }
    else{
    echo "Folder not empty"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One line for piping, by also using the `GetFileSystemInfos().Count` with a test :

```
gci -Directory | where { !@( $_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count) }
```

will show all directories which have no items. Result:

```
Directory: F:\Backup\Moving\Test

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         5/21/2021   2:53 PM                Test [Remove]
d-----         5/21/2021   2:53 PM                Test - 1   
d-----         5/21/2021   2:39 PM                MyDir [abc]
d-----         5/21/2021   2:35 PM                Empty
```

---

I post this because I was having edge-case issues with names that contained brackets `[ ]`; failure was when using other methods and the output piped to `Remove-Item` missed the directory names with brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a count from Get-ChildItem can provide false results because an empty folder or error accessing a folder could result in a 0 count.

The way I check for empty folders is to separate out errors:

```
Try { # Test if folder can be scanned
   $TestPath = Get-ChildItem $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable MsgErrTest -Force | Select-Object -First 1
}
Catch {}
If ($MsgErrTest) { "Error accessing folder" }
Else { # Folder can be accessed or is empty
   "Folder can be accessed"
   If ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($TestPath)) { # Folder is empty
   "   Folder is empty"
   }
}
```

The above code first tries to acces the folder. If an error occurs, it outputs that an error occurred. If there was no error, state that "Folder can be accessed", and next check if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into some of the existing answers, and experimenting a little, I ended up using this approach:

```
function Test-Dir-Valid-Empty {
    param([string]$dir)
    (Test-Path ($dir)) -AND ((Get-ChildItem -att d,h,a $dir).count -eq 0)
}
```

This will **first check for a valid directory** (`Test-Path ($dir)`). It will then check for any contents including any directories, hidden file, or "regular" files** due to the attributes `d`, `h`, and `a`, respectively.

Usage should be clear enough:

```
PS C_\> Test-Dir-Valid-Empty projects\some-folder
False
```

...or alternatively:

```
PS C:\> if(Test-Dir-Valid-Empty projects\some-folder){ "empty!" } else { "Not Empty." }
Not Empty.
```

---

** *Actually I'm not 100% certain what the defined effect of of `a` is here, but it does in any case cause all files to be included. The documentation states that `ah` shows hidden files, and I believe `as` should show system files, so I'm guessing `a` on it's own just shows "regular" files. If you remove it from the function above, it will in any case find hidden files, but not others.*