# Powershell - Correct Way of Checking if a directory is empty

Tags: powershell

What is the correct way of determining if a file or folder is empty in powershell? I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550128/powershell-test-if-folder-empty) and tried the example that the second user gave, and it worked.

Now, I've been checking if a directory is empty by using the length property, like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\" -Recurse).Length)
```

However, that only returns the number of bytes that the file/folder has. I tested the length property and found that if you were to have a blank text file/folder placed in the downloads then the length property wouldn't return the correct value.

Can you use the length property to correctly determine the number of files/folders that a directory has?

Comment: Why don't you use `Test-Path "C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\*"` as suggested in [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10550670/608772) answer of the same [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10550128/608772).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell test if folder empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550128/powershell-test-if-folder-empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it will count the number of items:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\" -Recurse | Measure-Object
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, however, why does the length property give the value that it does? Why doesn't it give the number of files/folders in a directory?

Comment: Because when you do a get-childitem call, then length property respresents the file size.

My example doesn't format well in this comment, but just do a get-childitem call by itself and you will see the length column.

For example:
PS>get-childitem


    Directory: C:\Users\Foo\Desktop


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        2013-04-20   9:51 PM            2013-01-22-antlrworks-2.0

Comment: Thanks again, I just tested your answer, but I had to modify it like this: (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\somerUser\Downloads\" -Recurse | Measure-Object) I had to place brackets around the command for it to return the proper value. Why?

Comment: You dont need any brackets at all, I didn't use them when I ran it.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to be sure a file or folder is empty you can use the following:

for a file:

```
If ((Get-Content C:\YouFile.txt) -eq $Null) {
    "The file is empty"
}
```

if the file contains white space it wont return as null, so if you want to check even white space you can use the following:

```
If ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace((Get-Content C:\YourFile.txt))) {
    "The file is empty"
}
```

for a folder:

```
If ((Get-ChildItem -Force C:\SomeFolder) -eq $Null) {
    "the Folder is empty"
}
```

Comment: Your folder example does not considered items with the hidden attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to handle this is just to use the base  static method in System.Io.Directory -- [Directory.EnumerationFileSystemInfos()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383358%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and see how many objects, if any, are returned. Note that a FileSystemInfo can be either a directory or file, so it'll work in your case.

```
[system.io.directory]::EnumerateFileSystemEntries("C:\temp")
```