# How to replace square brackets in powershell *[*

Tags: powershell

i want to replace a square bracket in powershell, to change the title.

my code:

```
if($finaltitlewithouterrors -like  "*`[*`]") {
    $finaltitlewithouterrors=$finaltitlewithouterrors.Replace("[", '')
   }
```

i tried other schemas but none of them work, like

```
if($finaltitlewithouterrors -like  "*`[*") {
    $finaltitlewithouterrors=$finaltitlewithouterrors.Replace("`[", '')
   }
```

i also tried it with

```
*``[*
```

i found a similar question ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094312/how-do-i-use-square-brackets-in-a-wildcard-pattern-in-powershell-get-childitem#:~:text=Square%20brackets%20can%20be%20used%20as%20a%20wildcard,and%20consequently%20the%20support%20in%20Powershell%20is%20spotty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094312/how-do-i-use-square-brackets-in-a-wildcard-pattern-in-powershell-get-childitem#:%7E:text=Square%20brackets%20can%20be%20used%20as%20a%20wildcard,and%20consequently%20the%20support%20in%20Powershell%20is%20spotty.))
but noting of it work.

for example i have a name called:

```
BatmanTheDarkNight[1].pdf
```

and the final name should look like:

```
BatmanTheDarkNight.pdf
```

or

```
BatmanTheDarkNight1.pdf
```

Comment: Change ```"*`[*`]"``` to ```"*``[*``]"``` or ```'`[*`]'```

Comment: Both answers below are going to be helpful. I would recommend, however, that you take some time and read and understand Microsoft's documentation on [Powershell Comparison Operators (including `-replace`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1) and [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the square bracket `[ ]` characters when using `-replace`. Here is a rough solution using `[regex]::Escape`

```
$fileName = "BatmanTheDarkNight[1].pdf"
$newFileName = $fileName -replace [Regex]::Escape("["), "" `
    -replace [Regex]::Escape("]"), ""

$newFileName
BatmanTheDarkNight1.pdf
```

Note the use of a backtick to chain `-replace` operations on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the regex `-replace` for this:

```
$finaltitlewithouterrors = 'BatmanTheDarkNight[1].pdf' -replace '[\[\]]'
# --> BatmanTheDarkNight1.pdf
```

Regex details:

```
[\[\]]     Match a single character present in the list below
           A [ character
           A ] character
```